# This is slow on my android device

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a scrolling list in my mobile app which I build using ionic 1.0.1. The list is quite choppy when scrolling. The text blurs a little when scrolling. I checked Facebook's app on my phone and it scrolls very nicely, no chopping and blur. I have created a code pen and was wondering if there is anything I can do to improve the performance of this:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJdpRz

**HTML:**

```
<html ng-app="mobileApp">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

  <title>Ionic List Bug</title>

  <link href="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

  <ion-content>
    <ion-item collection-repeat="item in items">
      <div class="list card">

        <div class="item item-avatar">
          <img src="mcfly.jpg">
          <h2>{{item}}</h2>
          <p>{{item}}</p>
        </div>

        <div class="item item-body">
          <img class="full-image" src="delorean.jpg">
          <p>
            {{item}}
          </p>
          <p>
            <a href="#" class="subdued">1 Like</a>
            <a href="#" class="subdued">5 Comments</a>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="item tabs tabs-secondary tabs-icon-left">
          <a class="tab-item" href="#">
            <i class="icon ion-thumbsup"></i> Like
          </a>
          <a class="tab-item" href="#">
            <i class="icon ion-chatbox"></i> Comment
          </a>
          <a class="tab-item" href="#">
            <i class="icon ion-share"></i> Share
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-content>

</body>

</html>
```

**JS:**

```
angular.module('mobileApp', ['ionic'])

.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
  if (!ionic.Platform.isIOS()) $ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);
})

.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.items = [];

  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $scope.items.push("Item " + i);
  }
}]);
```

Comment: have you tried doing a build with https://crosswalk-project.org/ my companies android app runs super smooth when we do builds with the crosswalk engine.

Comment: @JessPatton Thanks for the suggestion! No I have not. I have just read about it and it looks very promising I will give it a try. I still need to though figure out how to make ios scrolling more smooth.

Comment: hmm, in have never had any issue with scrolling on ios due its very up to date webview (although apple is evil to the core), but I have yet to use a collection repeat...are you pulling that much data that a collection repeat is needed? or could you swap it out for a infinite scroll and a ng-repeat?

Comment: It is about 50-100 cards. I have tried ng-repeat and it was a showed no difference. I have noticed though if I remove any one of the the big DIV sections from the cards the performance increases significantly (very smooth). Rendering even a little more html for each card may then be causing performance issues? I will maybe try to use some html/css tricks to avoid so much rendering of html elements. Essentially maybe try to modify the html to lessen the amount of code yet still achieve a similar layout.

Comment: you could try loading maybe 5 to 10 cards at at time then when you are about to hit the bottom of the list use http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionInfiniteScroll/ to grab more data.

Comment: I'll take a look at that. One question about crosswalk, if I am building for newer devices will it still help me?

Comment: yes, crosswalk is still better than the newest webview on android. Also you will get consistent results across all devices.

Answer (score 1):

There isnt much we can do right now, but for now you can put this is your `.config` , this will allow native scrolling. I did see a performance improvement in scrolling.

```
.config(function($ionicConfigProvider) {
  if(!ionic.Platform.isIOS())$ionicConfigProvider.scrolling.jsScrolling(false);
```

Comment: I might be mistaken, but don't I already have that in my code?

Comment: Did you edit? I'm sorry I must have been answering similar 2-3 questions. Might have got mixed up.